# Check if childproduct attribute text is empty

Tags: php, magento

im a bit confused getting the values, for empty values.

```
if (empty($childProducts[$productId]["productLabels"] = $product->getAttributeText('preorderdate'))) { 
            echo 'Empty';}
```

Erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Citing [PHP empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Is your PHP version 5.5?

Comment: Yes, is 5.5, but if i check the empty values for ProductLabels is returning Empty,Empty,Empty and then "productLabels":false,

Comment: Its is strange that you get a parse error then. Still a better way would be in my opinion to rewrite the code as suggested by the other answers

Comment: Sorry, i didn't  try this option, i tried the other other. let me check with this and i will come back with a comment.

Comment: No, i still cannot parse the empty values. i have tried, isset, empty and trim

Answer (score 0):

Well you're passing an expression to `empty()`.

> Note:
>
> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Source: [PHP `empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Assuming that you'd want to assign the value then rewrite your code:

```
// Assign the value outside the condition
$childProducts[$productId]["productLabels"] = $product->getAttributeText('preorderdate');

// empty expects a variable
if (empty($childProducts[$productId]["productLabels"])) {
  echo 'Empty';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$childProducts[$productId]["productLabels"] = $product->getAttributeText('preorderdate');
if (empty($childProducts[$productId]["productLabels"])) { 
      echo 'Empty';
}
```

By default `$product->getAttributeText('preorderdate');` should return false if not set

```
if ($childProducts[$productId]["productLabels"] = $product->getAttributeText('preorderdate');) { 
      echo 'Empty';
}
```

Comment: Whithout result, this is getting var spConfig = new Product.Config({EmptyEmptyEmpty,.... and then "productLabels":false, but i want to override false with other word to parse on javascript.